# "ng-true-value" and "ng-false-value" alternatives in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I was searching for the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` alternatives in `Angular 2` but i didn't get a result. Did they replace them with other tools ? I really need them. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is something. Do you have a concrete use case? This would make it easier to suggest workarounds.

Comment: so I have this checkbox `<input type="checkbox"[(ngModel)]="selected"  (Change)="addQuest($event)"/>` , it is obvious here that the `selected` value will be either `true` or `false` i want it to be the label (which is dynamic eg: {{xx}}) of the checkbox ..

Comment: Got it. I guess you would need a custom `ControlValueAccessor` that does that. I'm pretty sure Angular2 doesn't provide anything currently out of the box. Forms in general still need some polish.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: no answer??? @5313M

Comment: @AkshayKhale no , I'd used a workaround.

Comment: @selemmn.  I'm having the similar problem. What workaround did you used?

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ  in my comm above where there is a mentioned `<input type=..` you can extract the  `true/false` values from the implemented function `addQuest($event)` in TS file , exactly form from that `$event` object. Make a console.log for the event and see there you'll find whether the checkbox is a true or false.

Comment: You might need to create a directive using using @HostListener and listen to change event and do manipulation with values as you want

Comment: @ShubhamTakode, should see when the question was asked before posting comments (or downvoting): there was no such options in the angular-2 beta.0

Answer (score 2):

Workaround. For example we have the 'object' in the model with a 'flag' and one checkbox should set the flag to value "1" and another checkbox should set the flag to value "2", if the checkbox both unchecked the value should be "0", so:

```js
public setFlag(object: any, event: any): any {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('some-mark-class') && (object.flag == 0 || object.flag == 1)) {
    object.flag = 2;
  } else if (!event.target.classList.contains('some-mark-class') && (object.flag == 0 || object.flag == 2)) {
    object.flag = 1;
  } else {
    object.flag = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="hide-{{object.flag}}" [checked]="object.flag === 1" (change)="setFlag(object, $event)">
<input type="checkbox" name="dlte-{{object.flag}}" [checked]="object.flag === 2" (change)="setFlag(object, $event)" class="some-mark-class">
```

The solution might be not perfect and somehow clumsy but it's something and it works, so if you have some improvements, please do.

When I'll have some more time I'll try to do it in some sandbox if you want :).

**UPDATE:**
**Verson 2**
Better approach and flexibility

.ts file:

```js
public setFlag(obj: any, property: any, trueValue: any, falseValue: any): any {
  if (obj[property] === trueValue) {
    obj[property] = falseValue;
  } else {
    obj[property] = trueValue;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="hide-{{object.flag}}" [checked]="object.flag === 1" (change)="setFlag(object, 'flag', 1, 0)>
<input type="checkbox" name="dlte-{{object.flag}}" [checked]="object.flag === 1" (change)="setFlag(object, 'flag', 'true-value', 'false-value')>
```

In a function setFlag we take 4 parameters: object, property for the object, true-value and false-value which give us flexibility to set the value what we wish and do it without mark-class. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I think Experimenter answer is too long, so i am giving short one:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isActive" [checked]="isActive" name="active" (change)="isActive ? data.is_active = 1 : data.is_active = 0">
```

I am using just short-if.

Answer (score 0):

Use below directive from npm.
It is alternative to the ng-true-value and ng-false-value in angular 2
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nikiphoros/ngx-toggle